# How to figure out meaningful feature index for mesh triangle in ARSCNFaceGeometry

Tags: ios, arkit

Working in ARKit using ARSCNFaceGeometry I understand there are over 1000 feature indices.

I understand that there are hard-coded mesh indices for example "9" for nose. "42" for right eye etc.

But is there a detailed list of indices so I can work with specific parts of the face?

Additionally, there are comments everywhere that working with hardcoded indices is not future proof I could not find a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not exist, so I wrote an iOS app so others can benefit from it:

Face Mesh App on Apple App Store:

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/face-mesh/id1439354562?mt=8